# Whether a set containing the set of real numbers, the null set, and the interval [-r,r] where r is irrational positive is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I am not a pure mathematician but an engineering professor. Right now I am going through the first chapter of Topology without Tears by Morrison. One of the questions is as follows. A set T consists of a set of real numbers, the null set and the closed interval [-r,r] where r is irrational. The question is whether (T,R) form a topology where R is the set of real numbers. The answer seems to be an obvious Yes irrespective of whether r is rational or irrational since both intervals can be infinitely large and can contain arbitrarily large numbers. But I am suspicious as it seems to be too obvious and I think the actual answer is No.

Comment: I don't understand the remark about arbitrarily large numbers. Why not using the definition of a topology using union and finite intersection? Also, the question is unclear: does T contain every interval of the form $[-r,r]$ where $r$ is irrational, or only one of them?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem statement should clearly specify whether $r$ takes on one, fixed irrational value, or whether $r$ varies over all of the irrational numbers.

Comment: In other words, are we talking about a collection of subsets of the form $\{\mathbb R, \emptyset\} \cup \bigl\{[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]\bigr\}$? Or instead of the form $\{\mathbb R, \emptyset\} \cup \bigl \{[-r,r] \mid r \in \mathbb I\bigr\}$ where $\mathbb I$ is the set of irrationals?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Please clarify your post (see Taladris' and Lee's comments above) and include some more elaborate attempt. The aim of this exercise is to let you re-read the definition of what a topology is, so start from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is well known construction which is to open a side of a closed interval or close a side of an open intervals when you take either infinite unions or infinite intersections. For example: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[0,2-\frac{1}{n}\right] = [0,2)   $$ $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(0,2+\frac{1}{n}\right)=(0,2]$$
Since open sets are closed under infinite unions then consider the infinite union of sets in the form $[-r,r]$
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[-2\pi+\frac{1}{n} , 2\pi - \frac{1}{n} \right] = (-2\pi , 2\pi )$$
Which is not an open set in the form $[-r,r]$

Comment: Imo the question should not be answered before clarification (see comments) and attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Definition: A topology $T$ on a set $X$ is a collection of some or all of the subsets of $X$ such that

(i). $X\in T$ and $\emptyset\in T.$

(ii). For any $S\subseteq T,$  the common union $\bigcup S=\cup_{\sigma\in S}\;\sigma=\{x:\exists \sigma\in S\,(x\in\sigma)\}$ belongs to $T$.

(iii). For any $S\subseteq T$,  if $S$ is a FINITE collection then the common intersection $\bigcap S$ belongs to $T.$

From this we see that if $R$ is any set and if $U\subseteq R$ then $\{R,\emptyset,U\}$ is a topology on $R.$

Remarks: A topological space is a pair $(T,X),$ or, if you prefer, $(X,T),$ where T is a topology on $X.$ But it is extremely common to speak of "the space $X$". The members of $T$ are called the open sets, and their complements in $X$ are called closed sets. An infinite series of tutors has has to admonish students that  the assertions "If $U$ is not open then $U$ is closed"  and "If $U$ is open then $U$ is not closed" are true if $U$ is a DOOR,  but are not valid in topology. The definition of a topological space is very broad. The coarse (or "trivial") topology on $X$ is $\{X,\emptyset\}.$ The discrete (or "fine") topology on $X$ is $P(X)=\mathcal P(X)=\{Y: Y\subseteq X\}.$

Caution: Some authors use $Y\subset X$ to mean $Y\subsetneqq X$ while others use $Y\subset X$ to mean $(Y=X\lor Y\subsetneqq X)$...The definition of $\bigcap S$ is that if $S=\emptyset$ then $\bigcap S=\emptyset,$ and if $S\ne\emptyset$ then $\bigcap S=\{e:\forall \sigma\in S\,(e\in \sigma)\}.$ The reason for this distinction is that if $S=\emptyset$ then $\{e:\forall \sigma\in S\,(e\in \sigma)\}$ is everything that exists.

Comment: 1) This answer does not adress the question. 2) Imo the question should not be answered before clarification (see comments) and attempts. 3) "if $S=\emptyset$ then $\bigcap S=\emptyset$" is false.